# Searching in the search text field it will popup on a Jtable those data i want to delete, after it will show but when i delete it wont delete the data

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

In my JTable it displays all the names of people, and then when I type a name or any related info to them, then it will show until only one person is shown in the table. When I click that one row of the table and then click the button delete but it won't delete that specific data instead it deletes the first row in the table "before searching in the table."

This is the output:
[Before seaching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgPRI.jpg)

When Searching and after hitting the delete button above. That data is not been deleted.
[Searching](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXAIm.jpg)

But instead, it deleted who is in the first row
[After](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lxpbE.jpg)

This is the code for the delete that is connected to the button delete.

```
 private void officialsDelete() {
    DefaultTableModel RecordTable = (DefaultTableModel)officialTable.getModel();
    int SelectedRows = officialTable.getSelectedRow();
    
    try{
        if(officialTable.getSelectedRowCount() == 1){
            id = Integer.parseInt(RecordTable.getValueAt(SelectedRows, 0).toString());
            deleteItem = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Confirm if you want to delete item",
                    "Warning",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if(deleteItem == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
                Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dataConn,username,password);
                pst = sqlConn.prepareStatement("delete from officials where id =?");
                RecordTable.removeRow(officialTable.getSelectedRow());

                pst.setInt(1, id);
                pst.executeUpdate();
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Recorded Updated");
                upDateDBOfficials();

            }
            
        }else{
                if(officialTable.getRowCount()==0){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Table is Empty!");
                }else{
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this,"Please select Single row for Deleting");
                }
            }
        
    }catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InformationSystem.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(InformationSystem.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
                null, ex);
    }
    
}
```

And then this is the code for the keyReleased of the textfield for search.

```
private void officialsSearch() {
    String search = officialSearchTxt.getText();
    DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel)officialTable.getModel();
    TableRowSorter<DefaultTableModel> sorter = new TableRowSorter<>(model);
    officialTable.setRowSorter(sorter);
    sorter.setRowFilter(RowFilter.regexFilter("(?i)" + search));
    
}
```

My problem in here is need to delete the data in the table when i search in the textfield and it will appear in the JTable and click it to delete it. After clicking it in the table, i will now click the button delete for it to delete.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: You need to use the `JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(...)` to get the correct index of the row to delete from the `DefaultTableModel`.

Comment: In what part of it should be implemented? I'm not kind of familiar with JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(...)

Comment: When you filter a table the data is NOT removed from the model. When you filter the table to display "Jeremiah" you only have a single row in the view of the table so its index is now 0 in the JTable. However, in the model the index is still 4. So you need to convert the 0 to 4 before you can delete the data from the DefaultTableModel. The above method does this for you. I guess you update the model in your "removeRow(...) method. So you need to either pass the converted index or convert the index in that method.

Comment: As stated, `officialTable.getSelectedRow();` will return the "visual" row index.  You need to convert this to the "model" index using [`JTable#convertRowIndexToModel`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel(int)). You might also want to read through [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and pay attention to [Sorting and Filtering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) section

Comment: Oh, men! It work. I do really need that "JTable.convertRowIndexToModel(...)" I'm able to delete the search filter of the table. Thanks for your help. It really means a lot. @camickr

Comment: Yup, I do need to read more about this Sorting and Filtering. Thank you @MadProgrammer